# How does my project find files in Grunt's .tmp directory?

Tags: gruntjs

I currently am using a Yeoman seed project which comes with a Gruntfile and I'm having some trouble understanding parts of it. One particularly confusing thing is that during the development phase my SASS files are compiled into CSS and placed into a .tmp directory. My project however looks for main.css under app/styles yet the only thing there is my scss file. How is my project able to find main.css when it's not where it's looking?

```
./myApp
--Gruntfile.js
--.tmp
----main.css
--./app
----styles
------main.scss
```

When I create the dist folder the main.css file is placed correctly where it should be.
I think it may have to do with the compass or live-reload plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are talking about the situation when you ran `grunt serve`.

In the situation, the built-in server provides files under both `.tmp` and `app` directories by default which is specified for [grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#base) in Gruntfile like followings.

```
    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {

        ...

        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= config.app %>'
                ]
            }
        },
```

This is why `"styles/main.css"` in `index.html` file goes to `.tmp/styles/main.css`.

Comment: I think this is the key! I'm still somewhat confused here though because there are 2 bases. Wouldn't the project potentially find two files? Or is there some sort of cascade here where it first tries to find the file with .tmp as the base and if that can't be found it uses config.app?